# Whether to use "them" or "it"

Tags: grammar

I have a doubt about this sentence:

"If your product arrives broken our Returns Department will organise a replacement as long as you contact them within 24 hours of having received the parcel."

Can the "Returns Department" be referred to as "them" even though it is singular? Using "it" just doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: *Department* is a collective noun like *team, organization, government etc*. It can be thought of as *singular or plural*.

Comment: Thank you. Could another explanation be that Returns Department is genderless and therefore we can use "them" (as in "Someone is at the door, please show them in.")?

Comment: Then why can't it be **it**?. It is singular as well as neutral gender.

Comment: Using 'it' here sounds almost outlandish to my (British) ears. Using 'them' notionally (representing 'the people staffing' or equivalent) would be normal in the UK. I think the problem here is that 'it' is far more unpersonal and depersonalising than 'them' (and you've already actually referred to the people involved rather than the department per se in saying 'will organise a replacement') so people insisting on avoiding notional concord are probably better rephrasing.

Comment: No, you do not have a “doubt”: you have a question. Doubts are something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the same question can be observed at [dictionary.com](http://blog.dictionary.com/collective-nouns/). It responds to the question as:

> A **collective noun** refers to a whole group as a single entity but also
>   to the members of that group.
>
> A collective noun names a group of individuals or things with a
>   singular form. Examples of collective nouns are: faculty, herd, team.
>   There are collective nouns for people, animals, objects, and concepts.
>   The use of a singular or plural verb depends on the context of the
>   sentence. If one is referring to the whole group as a single entity,
>   then the singular verb is best: The school board has called a special
>   session. When a group noun is used with a singular determiner (e.g.,
>   a/an, each, every, this, that), singular verbs and pronouns are
>   normal: The team is away this weekend; they have a good chance of
>   winning. There are other contexts where the plural verb is more
>   natural: My family are always fighting among themselves. When the
>   individuals in the collection or group receive the emphasis, the
>   plural verb is acceptable. Generally, however, in *American English*,
>   collective nouns take singular verbs. In *British English*, collective
>   nouns are more often treated as plurals that take plural verbs.

I think there are still some debates on the topic, however.
So, when you refer to department as "them", you are actually refering to the people who work in that department, not the department itself.

Comment: Hello, Omid. This is a good answer as far as it goes (you don't mention the skewing towards  notionality already present in 'will organise a replacement' here), but has been given on ELU before.

Answer (score 0):

It can be either.

Using 'it' will keep the communication clinical.

Using 'them' will humanize the department.

Comment: The trouble is that 'Returns Department will organise a replacement' has **already** 'humanized the department', so reverting to 'it' is incongruous.

Comment: Disagree.  The department is organizing.  Farm equipment and computers organize.  Humanity is not referenced or implied.

Comment: So ''The school will organise a replacement" means the building is rather exceptional?

Comment: The term 'school' embodies warmth.  Who among us don't recognize a school as a body of students and teachers?  The term 'department' is far more generic.  It is not inherently imbued with humanity as is a school.

Comment: Here, 'X will organise a replacement' _must_ be seen as having a volitional (and hence sentient) agent. As in 'Parliament will vote on the matter today.'

Comment: Granted.  However, the author does have a choice between making this a clinical communication or one more warm.  Using 'it' will not be an egregious fault in agreement.

Comment: Not egregious, but (as OP seems also to appreciate) incongruous. Passivisation seems the more obvious clinical choice: "If your product arrives broken: as long as you contact our Returns Department within 24 hours of having received the parcel, a replacement will be provided / sent." Note that the original 'organized' is not too explicit.